# localhost:55555 only works with Opera

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, safari, localhost

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WebMatrix/IIS Express only works with Opera!](https://superuser.com/questions/308327/webmatrix-iis-express-only-works-with-opera)

[Older question...](https://superuser.com/questions/308327/webmatrix-iis-express-only-works-with-opera) Which is dead...
Basically, only Opera works opening localhost (IIS Express/WebMatrix).
For details on errors, please look at the previously linked question.

What can I do to test my website? >.>

Comment: Your older question may be "dead" (you only posted it yesterday...), but you should edit the original with more detail, or whatever you've been trying. This will bump it to the front page *and* provide more info for people to ask with.

Comment: It actually was two (2) days ago but SE seems to floor the values...

Comment: Good point, and you are right with respect to flooring of all date/time checks. Still it's always much better to tweak an old question (even ancient ones), but if you really *really* must post a new version of one of your previous questions you should delete the old one first.

Comment: Okay... I didn't know that editing them will bump them...